# Vim replace command after yanking a word

Tags: vim

suppose I yanked a word under cursor via "yiw", then I navigate to a word I wish to replace. Whats the key combination for replacing this very word with the one in the buffer?

Comment: It's "register", not "buffer".

Comment: How about `yiw` again.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

> Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 4.

Comment: does the job. However a 4 stroke key combo is not really convenient

Comment: Then add a mapping. Note that this will replace the content of the delete register with the replaced text, so you can't repeat the action.

Comment: Now why didn't I ever think of that :D

Comment: Vim is not designed to be convenient nor efficient.  Vim is designed to glue small commands together to complete tasks. This is an inherently inefficient process, but when editing large amounts of text, may be useful. Using a code editor (IDE) that has things like variable refactoring using multiple cursors is efficient. Vim is a text editor, not a code editor.